# arcgis 10.2 server how to get legend to display symbology only for visible classes

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

i have a web app that consumes legend info via a esri/dijit/Legend widget. The problem is that it displays symbology for all data, even those features not visible in current extent, is there a way to display only visible classes?